# PHP - Saving relationship - shared and unique references

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 models:

1. Stream
2. Field
3. Document
4. Result

I then have below relationships defined:

`Stream.php`:

```
public function fields()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}
public function documents()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
```

`Field.php`:

```
public function stream()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
}

public function result()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Result::class);
}
```

`Document.php`:

```
public function stream()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
}
```

`Result.php`:

```
public function field()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Field::class);
}
```

Now, my users can upload documents to a stream, and my users can create many fields on a stream.

When a document is uploaded to a stream,for each field defined, the document content will be parsed according to some logic I have created.

The end result of this parsing, should be saved to the database (`results`).

I can do this now, by:

```
$document = Document::find(1);

foreach($stream->fields as $field)
{
    $content = myParseFunction($document->content);

    $field->save(['content' => $content]);

}
```

This will create a result for each field on the stream. Like, if my Stream had 2 fields:

`results` table:

```
id | field_id | content 
1  | 1        | Lorem ipsum
2  | 2        | Another ipsum
```

Whenever I upload a new document however, the result will be overwritten.

**As each uploaded documents content is *unique***, how can I save the result for the field and *specific document*.

Like, if my Stream still have 2 fields, but I upload 2 documents:

`results` table:

```
id | field_id | document_id | content 
1  | 1        | 1           | Lorem ipsum
2  | 2        | 1           | Another ipsum
3  | 1        | 2           | Another unique content
4  | 2        | 2           | Yet another unique content
```

Comment: How is your resuls model set up?  Are you using the results table as a join table?

Comment: @Eva I just updated my question with the `Result` model code.

Comment: @Eva - currently I am not using the `results` table as a join table, as it currently only saves the content for the field - but not specific for the document. Could I do that with a join table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the result is also determined by the document, as you are parsing a document for a for a field.
I would also link the documents to theuse the Result table ans store the results there.
One result would be determinded by the document id and the field id.

Result

```
public function fields()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}

public function documents()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
```

Document

```
public function results()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
}
```

Field

```
public function stream()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
}

public function result()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Result::class);
}
```

And then:

```
$document = Document::find(1);
$result = new Result();

foreach($stream->fields as $field)
{
    $content = myParseFunction($document->content);

    $result->save(['field_id' => $field->id, 'document_id'=>$document->id, 'content' => $content]);

}
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the migration for the models? I can't seem to figure out the relationship setup in the database :(

Comment: @oliverbj I haven't doen the migration file. I am just adding 2 additional columns to the result table: document_id and content. So the documents are also linked to the results and I have moved the result content from field table to the result table.

Comment: Ah ok. In my question, the `table` shown is actually the `result` table (as it references the `fields` table). I will update my question to reflect this.

I will also try your code :)

Comment: I am not able to do: `$field->result()->create([])`, instead of creating a new instance of `Result();`?

Comment: @oliverbj that might work, and you only need to set the document_id and the content

Comment: thanks! I am just checking now, and I see that beside documents, emails can also be uploaded. So instead of having a `document_id` on the `results` table, can I make it a polymorphic relation instead? (So it can both reference a specific document or a specific email). And how do I save it in this case? As I cannot do `$field->result()->create([])` on a polymorphic, since it will then save the `App\Field` class.

Comment: You can make it polimorpthic, then you also need a model column to determine which model to link to. Laravel has a built in notifiacions table that is using ploymorphic data, you can have a look at that how it is done.:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#database-notifications

Comment: I have checked the documentation and tried to implement it, but I simply cannot figure out how to fetch the unique result for the specific email / document..